# Open dialog get path from file explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-explorer

i try to explain my problem, but it is not easy...

(I'm working on two monitor it's important.)
So, in my old win 7 system somehow I am causing that:
if i have open a file dialog (for example photoshop open dialog)
on my right monitor AND i click (just click!) an open file explorer
on the left monitor then the file dialog GET the path from the
file explorer.
I reinstall my win, and spent a lot of hours of google this
but i can do it again :(

Someone?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome tibo, I'm having a hard time understanding your problem. To clarify, you have an open file dialog open in photoshop, you click a file explorer window and it puts the path of that window into your open dialog?

Comment: Absolute yes! :)

Comment: Nobody.........?